# App crashes on googleApiClient.connect();

Tags: android, api

I have an app, and I want to add Google Play achievements. I followed this:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

I have this at my manifest (with the right ID):

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
    android:value="000000000000" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="000000000000" />
```

I have this OnStart:

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    try
    {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Exception error;
        error = e;
    }
}
```

With debuging, when the ".connect()" is executed, it crashes, and "TRY CATCH" doesn´t detect it.
This is my "OnCreate()".

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   googleApiClient =  new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
            .build();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lanzarFragments();
}
```

This is how my "MainActivity" is declared:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

My GoogleApiClient, is declared like I show here:

```
public static  GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
```

I want to add, that the method "lanzarFragments()", starts a Fragment. All my app is with fragments, changing one by another. But I just have one Activity, the Main, that has the "OnCreate()" I wrote up.

Some Idea about what it crashes and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Try adding `e.printStackTrace();` inside your `catch` block. Then add the logs to your question.

Comment: What I did before for to try, was to put a breakpoint. For that reason I know that the process doesn´t goes to the catch block. I did what you say, but I don´t know to find the execution on the log. I have to much text. I am looking at "Android monitor", "Verbose" mode, "Show only selected Aplication".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in onStart():

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

in onStop();

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

This is from [Official Docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init). You don't need a try / catch for this method hence why the exception is not getting called.

Could you post your logcat also please to see in more detail as without it others wont be able to find out the exact problem.

Comment: I tried and it doesn´t work. It is from the link I pasted on the question ;)

Comment: Logcat has more than 6000 lines.

Comment: Make sure 'show only selected application' is on for logcat output and look for any lines that are in red and have the letter 'E' after your package name.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did, and I found the problem. It was at the Manifest. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to have helped, but was exactly was it in your manifest please, was it your values for your metadata ?

Comment: The problem was, that I wrote my APP_ID there, in the manifest, between ("). And it was detected as numeric. The fixing was to use the string value file.

Comment: Ah right glad it's sorted and thanks for letting others know.